# New in an IT infrastructure project company - what to do first?

Tags: product-management

If a project manager with a software development background assigned as a project manager for an IT infrastructure project company, what should be done first? Let me know your innovative ideas

Comment: Hi Nuwan, welcome to PMSE! Stack Exchange sites (including PMSE) are focused on objective and non-pooling questions. The way your question is currently structured as of now, however, is too broad and it's likely to be closed as off-topic. Read our [FAQ] to have some insights on what's ok and what's not ok to ask here. Feel free to amend the question as much as you want, making it more focused in specific problems.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do on any project is to define finish.  If this is unknown, like for projects where you are building something new, including research and development, then define the finish of the first phase.  Everything builds off of finish: scope statement and WBS, project charters, plans, schedules, and on and on.